# How to Use If Within Input Div to show Message to User basis Database Value

Tags: php, html, mysql, if-statement

I am getting goof up, can someup help like

v_central_locking value can either be 0 or 1

Below is the code to display value - fetched from database

```
       <?php
           <!--box start-->
            <div class="common-box">
                <div class="common-box-left">Central Lock</div>
                <div class="common-box-right">
                <input name="Central Lock" type="text" class="text-box" value="'.$rows->v_central_locking .'" readonly=""/>               
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--box end-->
       ?>
```

How to have it with If clause in div where if value is zero - it will display message Like

```
      if (v_central_locking==0)
      { 
       echo 'Doesnt Have';
      }
       else
      { 
       echo 'Yes a Feature';
      }
```

can someone help pls

**Modified**

```
   <?php
 <!--box start-->
            <div class="common-box">
                <div class="common-box-left">Central Lock</div>
                <div class="common-box-right">
                    <input name="Central Lock" type="text" class="text-box" value="'. ($rows->v_central_locking == 0) ? 'Yes' : 'Yep' .'" readonly=""/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--box end-->
     ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
<!--box start-->
<div class="common-box">
    <div class="common-box-left">Central Lock</div>
    <div class="common-box-right">
    <input name="Central Lock" type="text" class="text-box" value="<?php echo ($rows->v_central_locking == 0) ? 'Nope' : 'Yep'; ?>" readonly=""/>               
    </div>
</div>
<!--box end-->
```

For reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

**After your edit**

You cannot simply put HTML code within PHP tags like that. You should add an echo and adjust your code like the following:

```
<?php
    echo '
    <!--box start-->
    <div class="common-box">
        <div class="common-box-left">Central Lock</div>
        <div class="common-box-right">
            <input name="Central Lock" type="text" class="text-box" value="' . ($rows->v_central_locking == 0? 'Nope' : 'Yep') . '" readonly=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--box end-->';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, edited my query - box is already surrounded with php tag - modified query - but its not helping - can you suggest an edit in the code